# Populating a Federation ID when implementing SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We are about to implement SSO, with Azure being the Identity Provider.

If we use Federation ID to be the unique identifier for SSO how will we populate the Federation ID field in Salesforce ? Is it up to us to populate the field whether it's manually or by some import of a list ? Or is there some kind of way of having the field populated ?

Also - if that is a one time mass population of the current User accounts how do we populate that field for new Users ?

Thank you.

Comment: This can be done either using data loader or using manual record update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If we use Federation ID to be the unique identifier for SSO how will we populate the Federation ID field in Salesforce ?

You have a number of options available to you. For example, you could write an [AuthProviderPluginClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm) implementation to automatically resolve users, use the Data Loader to load the Federation ID values, or write a small Execute Anonymous script. There are numerous ways to get the users updated, you just have to choose whatever you think would be easiest.

> Also - if that is a one time mass population of the current User accounts how do we populate that field for new Users ?

You use [Just-in-Time Provisioning for SAML](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_jit_about.htm&type=5). You can enable standard provisioning, which should take their identity assertion and place it in the Federation ID field, or you can customize the JIT class that is generated in order to customize the behavior to do whatever it is you want to to when a new user is created.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @sfdcfox ! Question for new users (sorry if this stupid) - I read the JIT reference you made about automating the SF user and it is really great. But if the SF user account gets created the first time the user logs into SF then how would Azure link that login to their Federation ID ? Would they be using their Federation ID as their SF username in that first login ? If so, would the username in their newly created user account be their Federal ID ? Thanks again. I really appreciate your input.

Comment: @Zoom_v With SSO, Salesforce is the Service Provider (SP), and Azure is the IdP (Identity Provider). The SP redirects the client to the IdP, the user logs in with the IdP credentials, and then a SAML assertion is sent back to the SP, which uses the identity provided to link the session to a user. In SP mode, the user never directly logs in to Salesforce, might not know their username, and will have no password. If permitted, they can set a new password in Salesforce after creation.